# Read and print Line between two tags

Tags: shell, tags

I stuck into another problem of reading text between two tags through shell script. The file be

```
**# Enter IP Details, File Name of Machine here.
[SERVER]
TESTTAM
[/SERVER]

[SCRIPTNAME]
hdw.sh
[/SCRIPTNAME]**
```

and many such tags. Could anyone through some light on how to read lines between tags **[SERVER]** and **[/SERVER]** and store in a file. Later I will read this output file with some other script.

I also want to to do the same for other tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GNU sed`, matching the pattern and printing the only the line without the headers.

```
sed -n "/\[SERVER\]/,/\[\/SERVER\]/p" file | sed '1d;$d'
TESTTAM
```

(and)

```
sed -n "/\[SCRIPTNAME\]/,/\[\/SCRIPTNAME\]/p" file | sed '1d;$d'
hdw.sh
```

Comment: That works really good..Thanks Inian...by the way, I do I remove the last empty line created after sed operation in the file.

Comment: That works really good..Thanks Inian...by the way, How do I remove the last empty line created after sed operation in the file.

Comment: @Ram: It is not producing an empty line for me, how is it present?

Comment: I already upvoted, but it says I should have more than 15 reputation to so that the upvote will be viewed publicly. By the way, I trying to run the commands in Windows with cygwin.